# Why can't I retrieve a return value from a function with another function?

Tags: javascript, html

Why won't this work?

Var "i" works fine, and the return value can be seen, just not when I try to send the var "i" like I have bellow.

Button that send to deor_viewer function:

```
<div onclick="deor_viewer('deor','films_deor_ip_full_','1','.jpg')"></div>
```

The function:

```
function deor_viewer(folder,name,id,ext) {

    var x;
    x = 'url(assets/images/films/'+ folder + '/' + name  + id + ext;

    document.getElementById("deor_ip_viewer_id").style.backgroundImage = x; 

    var i = id;
    return i;                                                                                                               

};
```

An HTML button calls this function:

```
function viewer_right() {
    var test = deor_viewer();
    alert(test);
}
```

`alert` just comes up as "undefined"

It will work fine, just not when the `return` is sent with the `var`

Comment: All your parameter are undefined in that call, including `id`, and so will be the `i` variable?!

Comment: _“just not when the `return` is sent with the `var`”_ — what do you mean by that?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I mean if I set return with a hard value like return"Hello" it will work fine.  The alert will display Hello

Comment: @NewCodeMan what are you expecting the alert to show ?

Comment: I want it to return the "id"

Comment: @NewCodeMan please edit your question to add the way you really call the function.

Comment: And the "id" is receiving a value fine from an html btn

Comment: @NewCodeMan it obviously isn't.

Comment: Ok I added the btn that sends values to deor_viewer function

Comment: Do you expect that the next time you call your function its parameters will be kept?

Comment: I was. Is that wrong?

Comment: Yes, you need to pass them each time you call a function

Answer (score 2):

That is because the `deor_viewer` function expects 4 arguments, one of which is the `id` which you later assign to `i` and return it.

But when you call that function (*in your code*) you pass no arguments to it, so the `id` is `undefined` and that is what you get back.

```js
function deor_viewer(folder,name,id,ext) {

    var x;
    x = 'url(assets/images/films/'+ folder + '/' + name  + id + ext;

    document.getElementById("deor_ip_viewer_id").style.backgroundImage = x; 

    var i = id;
    return i;                                                                                                               

};
```

```html
<div onclick="alert(deor_viewer('deor','films_deor_ip_full_','1','.jpg'))">click me</div>

<hr/>

<div id="deor_ip_viewer_id">element with id=deor_ip_viewer_id</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `deor_viewer` function without arguments, so the `id` argument will be `undefined`, and you are assigning it to the variable `i` and returning that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your function `deor_Viewer` works just fine, It's when you call your other function that it breaks, because you aren't passing anything in to either of the functions. You have to pass values any time you call the function if you're expecting & referencing those values within the function.

It's this that you need to update with the parameters

```
// like this:
function viewer_right(folder,name,id,ext) {
    var test = deor_viewer(folder,name,id,ext);
    alert(test);
}

// then call it the same way
<div onclick="viewer_right('deor','films_deor_ip_full_','1','.jpg')">DIV</div>
```

So you end up with this, where you pass the agruments through `viewer_right` and into `deor_viewer`:

```js
    function deor_viewer(folder,name,id,ext) {

        var x;
        x = 'url(assets/images/films/'+ folder + '/' + name  + id + ext;

//document.getElementById("deor_ip_viewer_id").style.backgroundImage = x; 

        //var i = id;
        console.log('id', id);
        return id;                                                                                                               

    };
    
    // like this:
    function viewer_right(folder,name,id,ext) {
        var test = deor_viewer(folder,name,id,ext);
        alert(test);
    }

    // then call it the same way
```

```html
<div onclick="deor_viewer('deor','films_deor_ip_full_','1','.jpg')">deor_viewer</div>
<div onclick="viewer_right('deor','films_deor_ip_full_','1','.jpg')">viewer_right</div>
```